# How to use a variable to assign a database to each user in Laravel 5.3 in LAMP?

Tags: php, laravel, lamp

i have a little application for stock control in a shop wich is running in my online homemade server (lamp), i made my web app with laravel, now i have to use it to control more shops, so my idea is that when a user login in the app, he only can access to his own database, so i think i have to pass a variable with the databasename that correspond to every specific shop. how can i do that? is it right to create a virtualhost for each shop(now it could be 6 but can increase in the future)? or should i use one virtualhost and resolve the database assignment programatically in the webapp? all suggestions are welcome. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for voted to close but I think it's better on ServerFault http://serverfault.com/ ? No bad feeling please :)

Comment: @LionelChan - This is actually application layer and not DB layer, Simply the OP is asking how to assign a php variable within the laravel application and not a database variable one assumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a pro with laravel by any stretch however i imagine There is a couple of ways you could do this, That being said you should consider security issues when assigning a database variable / connection based on the users values.

An example would be to create a database table that holds each shops database name, That way you can make a request to the database and request the database name for that specific shop.

```
  ID |  Shop_Database_name
-----+-----
   1 | myshop1
   2 | myshop2
   3 | myshop3
```

Then you can build your database connection based on the shop_database_name stored in a master table.

```
DB::select('shop_database_name')->where('id', $shop->id)->first();

// Now you will build a database connection using something like:

$shopDatabase = DB::connection('shop_database_name')->select(...);
```

You can also pre-configure your `config/database.php` with multiple databases for each shop however if you have many shops sign up this would not be the best approach and I would recommend you have an overall table that holds all your database names for each shop.

If I am on the wrong path feel free to let me know and i will try to help where I can.